# Statsmodels ANOVA/Python: ValueError: must have at least one row in constraint matrix

Tags: python, statsmodels, valueerror, anova

I have a very large dataframe (12,000 rows x 95 columns) and I am wanting to loop through each column and run an ANOVA, appending the results to a list.

```
results = []

for i in df.columns[1:]:
    mod = ols('var ~ C({})'.format(i), data = df).fit()
    aov = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod, typ = 2)

    results.append(aov)
```

I ran this same code on a few columns individually, and also with the first 5 columns in this loop and both worked. However, when I run on the entire dataset, I get this error:

```
ValueError: must have at least one row in constraint matrix
```

As it worked with the first 5 columns, I assume it is something to do with my data, but I am unsure what and where.

I'm not very experienced with python but I think the error is arising at around line 50 in this code block (https://github.com/pydata/patsy/blob/master/patsy/constraint.py)

Answer (score 0):

After a whole lot of trial and error I have found the problem.

For some reason a dataframe of more than 64 columns would not work. Splitting my original data frame into two and running each of them separately fixed the problem.